# Accidentally altered a built-in python program, cannot make email-related python programs

Tags: python, django

I accidentally changed a built-in python program, either one that came with my computer or came with python, and is now bugging up every time I try to make a python email program of my own (such as the one mentioned in line 1 of the error below). I have no idea how I caused this error, the furthest I can specify is that I was practicing the code of some python Youtuber. The code he had ended up being similar to this one below that I didn't program, the one with the error raised at line 47.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my_email.py", line 1, in <module>
    import smtplib #actual sending function
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/smtplib.py", line 47, in <module>
    import email.utils
  File "/Users/jakedobronski/Documents/email.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .abstract import AbstractRegexLinkResolver
SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import
```

This is not a program that I have written and am not sure how it has been changed to become erred. I'd try the suggestions of similar articles if it didn't risk causing further damage, error, and confusion.

Comment: smtplib.py is importing your email.py on ~/Documents instead of the email.py expected

Comment: If your new program is called `email.py` then change its name, it looks like there is a name collision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

smtplib.py is importing email module:

```
import email.utils
```

But it's finding it under your Documents folder instead of the [smtp email module](https://fossies.org/dox/Python-2.7.12/smtplib_8py_source.html).
/Users/jakedobronski/Documents/email.py
Which contains unexpected code.

Try changing the name of your email.py file to see if it fixes.